# What is the difference between data() and get()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a hard time understanding the difference between calling `get()` (without arguments) or `data()` on a `DocumentDeltaSnapshot`. Here is [a link to the reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot#data)

The docs are particularly vague about `get` I think:

> The parameter supplied for this method must be the key of the data to retrieve.

But you can call it without a key.

> Value must not be null.

As I read it, value here refers to the return value. So what happens if the key is incorrect?

Is `get` just a more flexible alternative to `data`, or am I overlooking something fundamental?

----- edit ----

My confusion seems to come from the fact that there are two types of `get`. One you use to retrieve the document snapshot, and one to access specific fields in the document data.

```
const ref = db.collection("someCollection").doc("someDocumentId");
const value = await ref
  .get()
  .then(doc => doc.get("someProperty"));
  // or for the whole document do
  .then(doc => doc.data());
```

What makes it more confusing is that the SDK type definitions for Typescript also happily let me do this:

```
const value = await ref
  .get()
  .then(doc => doc.data().get("someProperty"));
```

Which will result in a runtime error because .get doesn't exist on the return value of data().

But to clarify: the first `get` call can not have any arguments. The second `get` call requires always 1 argument. So `data` can be used in place of the second `get` where you want the complete document data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#reading_data) suggests that `data()` is for accessing the entire document as a JavaScript object, while get() is accessing individual fields.

> You can use the get function to access specific fields:
>
> ```
> // Fetch data using standard accessors
> const age = event.data.data().age;
> const name = event.data.data()['name'];
>
> // Fetch data using built in accessor
> const experience = event.data.get('experience');
> ```

The way I read the API docs, the string you pass to `get()` can not be null.  You must provide the name of some property to access from the document.

Comment: You are right. But I've explained where the confusion came from.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that's confusing. It turns out that the Cloud Functions API and the Firestore client API are actually driven by different teams, so they may have evolved independently and had a confusing collision here.

Comment: That is exactly the impression I get when I try to work my way through the documentation. I hope they manage to merge things a bit in the near future.